# Show different templates when the browser gets resized for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, slds-grid

I am trying to create an LWC that comprises of 5 child bricks inside of a parent layout container. I am using these wrapped in lightning-layout-item and layout respectively. In between each of the bricks are vertical lines (using divs with left border styles) functioning as separators. What I am trying to achieve is once the user resizes the browser and the chart bricks start to wrap to a new row, I want to show another template that just has the bricks without the vertical lines in between so when they wrap, the lines don't show as it looks awkward to me.

It would be nice if there was a property I could access to do this, but I could only find form factor which doesn't really help. I did some rough implementation involving a resize event listener that checks if the window inner width is less than the full screen avail width property, and that works, but it feels kind of janky. This is because if the window is even slightly less than full-size, it will switch to the alternate template even if the child components are not yet wrapping to the next line. This is especially apparent when I connect my laptop to a larger monitor and I know that I still have a while of resizing the window smaller before the bricks wrap. It works, but I am wondering if LWCs provide anything natively better suited for this or if I need to keep going with the native JS scripting for this.

Comment: lwc works fine with standard media queries in css so you can conditionally show and hide your elements.

If you show some code we can help you where that needs to be added

Comment: I was thinking media queries as a possibility but was focused on using the template if:else directives. So with media queries I would just have two of my templates wrapped in classes and display: none the one I do not want to show depending on the width?

Comment: without seeing your code it is hard to suggest the best approach for your specific scenario.